# How do I assign a Converter from view class to Resource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Here is part of my FooPage.xaml

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- I want this is regionToTextConverter from my FooPage.cs, how to do it? -->
    <wpfCore:StringArrayToTextConverter
        x:Key="regionConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

And somewhere also in this FooPage.xaml

```xml
<ListViewItem>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="Something" />
        <!-- I want to use regionToTextConverter from Page class here -->
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding someValue, Mode=OneWay,
            Converter={StaticResource regionConverter}}" />
    </DockPanel>
</ListViewItem>
```

Now part of my FooPage.cs:

```
public StringArrayToTextConverter regionToTextConverter { get; private set; }

//Somewhere else
// additionalValueMapping is a dictionary
    regionToTextConverter = new StringArrayToTextConverter()
    {
        additionalValueMapping = regionMapping
    };
```

My question is, how do I use the `regionToTextConverter` from page instance in the xaml view? StaticResource may not be an option here because I need to some logic specifically in this case, I want to know how to correctly use it in this scenario.

Comment: Your question is confusing. The instance of "regionConverter" is a StaticResource and you want to use it in code behind while you don't want StaticResource?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited description. I'm not sure StaticResource is a valid option, but if it is then I want to know how to use it. Also, I want to use "regionToTextConverter", not the xaml created "regionConverter". But if there is someway that "regionConverter" can redirected to "regionToTextConverter", it would also be good.

Comment: I am still not sure what is your intension. You can get the instance of StringArrayToTextConverter instantiated in XAML by `this.Resources["regionConverter"] as StringArrayToTextConverter` in code behind.

Comment: @emoacht You're right, this is how I solved this today. Instead of passing the Converter to the Binding thing in xaml, I should retrieve the instance from resource and modify it there. 
However I still want to know how to do this other way around, so that the object created from c# code, can act as an object, and pass to that binding thing.
I tried using Binding to that converter, and there is error that this converter is not dependency object.

Answer (score 0):

To create a converter in the code-behind of your `FooPage` and use it in XAML, just add it to the `Resources` of the page as you would do in XAML. However, you can only add it before the call to `InitializeComponent`, otherwise the resource is not available via the `StaticResource` extension. Using `DynamicResource` here is not applicable, because `Converter` is not a dependency property.

```
public partial class FooPage : Page
{
   public FooPage()
   {
      Resources.Add("regionConverter", new StringArrayToTextConverter()
      {
         additionalValueMapping = regionMapping
      });
      InitializeComponent();
      
      // ...other code.
   }

   // ...other code.
}
```